# Value off indefinite integral at a point a, does it represent area?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, area

If we have a function f and it's antiderivative F then the definite integral of of f from a to be (F(a)-F(b)) represents the area under the curve of f from point a to point b. But what does the value of the indefinite integral at a point (F(a)) represent? If it represents area then from what point to what point?

Comment: $F(a)$ is just a value of antiderivative function at point $a$. Btw, the area is $F(b)-F(a)$ if $a$ is the lower bound.

Comment: Vasili thank you very much

Comment: So F(a) does not represent area but the difference between F(a) and F(b) represents area.

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, although if there is a point $c$ such as $F(c)=0$ then $F(a)$ can represent an area.